# Why keyDown(shift) function is not working for python pyautogui for Excel Automation

Tags: excel, python-3.x

`keyDown(shift)` function is not working for Python pyautogui for Excel Automation
When I have to copy all values from above cell in Excel

Here is my code

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.hotkey('right','right','ctrl','up')
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','d')
```

Comment: First, it seems you are sending Ctrl+D instead of Ctrl+C to copy. Also, while you are holding down the shift key, you are only pressing Ctrl. I think you want to call keyDown() on 'ctrl' after sending the 'right' keystrokes. And you want to call press() instead of hotkey()

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found that can solve this issue is:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('shiftleft')
pyautogui.keyDown('shiftright')
pyautogui.hotkey('right','right','ctrl','up')
pyautogui.keyUp('shiftleft')
pyautogui.keyUp('shiftright')
```

So, you have to make left and right shifts down at the same time to activate this feature which is wired.